# set of linear and continuous functions

Tags: analysis

Let E,F be normed vector spaces
$ \mathcal L(E,F) = \{ f \in Hom(E,F) | f-continuous\} $

Why
1) $Hom(\Bbb K^n,\Bbb K) = \mathcal L (\Bbb K^n,\Bbb K) = \Bbb K^n $
2) $\mathcal L (\Bbb K^n, F) = F^n$

Comment: I bet *some* relation **must** exist between $\;F\;$ and $\;\Bbb K\;$...of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part of 1) says that any linear map $\Bbb K^n\to \Bbb K$ is continuous (or equivalently, *bounded*). If you want to prove it, show that a sequence $v_k$ in $\Bbb K^n$ is convergent iff all the coordinate sequences $(v_k)_i$ are convergent (for the particular norm considered in $\Bbb K^n$). Then any linear $f:\Bbb K^n\to\Bbb K$ will be uniquely determined by the $n$ values $f(e_i)$ where $(e_i)$ is the standard basis of $\Bbb K^n$, so if you have a sequence $v_k$ converging to $w$ of $\Bbb K^n$ then write $f(v_k)=f\left(\sum_i (v_k)_i\,e_i\right) = \sum_i (v_k)_i\,f(e_i)$ by linearity, which is a finite sum of *numbers*, and each coordinate sequence $(v_k)_i$ converges to $w_i$, so we have $\ f(v_k)\ \to\ \sum_i(w_i)\,f(e_i)=f(w)$.

2) Exactly the same works for any normed space $F$ as codomain, with the difference that $f(e_i)$ will be a vector in $F$ instead of a scalar. The main observation is that any linear map $f:\Bbb K^n\to F$ is uniquely determined by the $n$ vectors $f(e_1),\, \dots,\ f(e_n)$.